# Access to US Supreme Court brief

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, us-supreme-court, legal-research, online

does anyone have access to the American edition of Westlaw? I’m trying to get hold of a copy of the US Supreme Court brief under reference 2000 WL 432367, any pointers or help appreciated!

Comment: SCOTUS briefs are usually available for free online somewhere. I think SCOTUS blog maintains a set of links to them. https://www.scotusblog.com/ They can also be found on PACER (which is a free except for nominal pennies per page download charges over $X a quarter) which is the federal government's official online public access gateway for all federal court filings. The case name and date should be enough to locate it within either resource.

Comment: Not from as long ago (!) as 2000 sadly.

Comment: Identifying the brief would be helpful.

Comment: FYI. Most lawyer Westlaw subscriptions (judges get de facto free Westlaw) have a per search surcharge for legal briefs as opposed to court opinions.

Comment: @bdb484 It’s the reply brief for the petitioners.

Comment: @zarka For what case?

Comment: @bdb484 Boy Scouts of America v Dale

Comment: The one-hour oral argument is online at https://www.oyez.org/cases/1999/99-699